# Delete all documents from index using ElasticsearchOperations

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete all the documents from particular index of ES using the following code:

```java
@Autowired
protected ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {
    Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery()).build();
    elasticsearchOperations.delete(query, elasticsearchOperations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(ReviewRequestDocument.class));
}
```

which fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id must not be null
```

I'm puzzled, because similar approach works for counting documents in index:

```java
private long countReviewRequestDocuments() {
    Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery()).build();
    return elasticsearchOperations.count(query, ReviewRequestDocument.class);
}
```

So my question is what is the correct way to remove all documents from index?

Comment: What version of ElasticSearch? And what ES client are you using exactly as mentioned in your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` file?

Comment: It's `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.9.3`

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Comment: Google `DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder` - that should find you something. You're using the search query while you need the delete by query API called.

Comment: are there documents in the index or might it be empty? Can you provide a minimal reproducable example and open an issue in Spring Data Elasticsearch (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues)

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments, I've found the solution, it's slightly similar to what was described previously at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362887/spring-data-elasticsearch-bulk-index-delete-millions-of-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```java
@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {
  IndexCoordinates coordinates = elasticsearchOperations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(ReviewRequestDocument.class);

  Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery()).build();
  String[] ids = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, ReviewRequestDocument.class, coordinates)
          .stream()
          .map(SearchHit::getId)
          .toArray(String[]::new);

  Query idsQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(idsQuery().addIds(ids)).build();
  elasticsearchOperations.delete(idsQuery, ReviewRequestDocument.class, coordinates);

  assertThat(countReviewRequestDocuments()).isZero();
}
```

it looks like ES does not allow bulk removal of all documents in index, so the solution is to fetch ids and then pass them into delete query.

Comment: This is highly ineffective. What if your index contains 100.000 entries? You'd retrieve them all, then reduce them to an array of ids and send this back. I can run your delete query without any problems.

Comment: Yeah, this is far from optimal. How would you make it faster?

Comment: as I wrote, the `delete(Query)` with the matchall works for me

Comment: @P.J.Meisch could you please put the whole code as the answer to my question?

Comment: I just use the code from your first code snippet, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

deleting all the documents from an index is super inefficient in Elasticsearch and is not the way to go about this

you are far better off deleting the index and then recreating it from code